# Python Selenium - Constantly changing web element ID

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I'm trying to use Selenium to find a web element that I know is the To field in a web email application (please see picture). I am able to successfully identify this web element and use send_keys to send an email address to this field.

However, the issue is the id always seems to cycle between 299 and 3 other numbers like 359 or 369.
Here's the code Im using. Is there another way I can account for this changing ID?

```
to_field = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "v299-to-input")))
print(to_field)
to_field.send_keys(email_reciever)
```

[image]

Thanks

PS- The web email application is fastmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the ID attribute is changing, you have to build your locator on some other, stable parameter. The following CSS Selector is stable:

```py
to_field = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".s-compose-to textarea")))
print(to_field)
to_field.send_keys(email_reciever)
```

The same can be done with the use of XPath locator:

```py
to_field = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'s-compose-to')]//textarea")))
print(to_field)
to_field.send_keys(email_reciever)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following `css selector` to identify the element.

```
to_field = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "textarea[id$='-to-input']")))
print(to_field)
to_field.send_keys(email_reciever)
```

This will identify the element `id` ends with the `-to-input` static value

```
to_field = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "textarea.v-EmailInput-input")))
print(to_field)
to_field.send_keys(email_reciever)
```

This will identify the element with `tagname.classname`

Comment: The second part will not work since that locator is not unique

Comment: @Prophet : how? this is the `classname`  and i can't see any dynamic value in it `v-EmailInput-input`.

Comment: You didn't open the email composing page on fastmail.com but I do :) There are 4 elements matching this locator there

Comment: @Prophet : Ok got your point, That's true I didn't check the url :-)

Comment: It's not just URL. You will have to pass registration there